# IntentService working on emulator but not on real device

Tags: android, alarmmanager, intentservice

My background IntentService is triggering perfectly after every 1 minute on Emulator but it is not running at all on an actual device, can anyone tell me why?
The phone i am using is Android Infinix.

In my MainActivity's onCreate method i have:

```
AlarmManager alarmMgr = (AlarmManager) MainActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, RemoveDownloadService.class);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse("First"));
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intent, 0);

    // Set the alarm to start at 2:00 p.m.
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 18);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 32);


    // Repeat every 24-hours
    alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
            1000 * 60 * 1, pendingIntent);
```

My Manfiest File:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.macbookpro.videodownload">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".DownloadListActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    </activity>
    <service
        android:name=".RemoveDownloadService"
        android:exported="false"/>
</application>
```

IntentService Class:

```
public class RemoveDownloadService extends IntentService {

public static final String LOG_TAG = "RemoveDownloadService";

public RemoveDownloadService() {
    super(LOG_TAG);
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent workIntent) {
    String str = workIntent.getDataString();
    ArrayList<VideoDownloadEntity> arrDownloads = new ArrayList<>();
    arrDownloads = DatabaseHandler.getHelper(getApplicationContext()).getVideoDowloads();
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), str, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP, 25, 400);
    toast.show();
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
    String nowDateStr = dateFormat.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
    try {
        Date nowDate = dateFormat.parse(nowDateStr);
        if(arrDownloads.size()>0)
        {
            for(VideoDownloadEntity downloadEntity: arrDownloads)
            {
                Date downloadedDate = dateFormat.parse(downloadEntity.getVideoDownloadDate());
                long diff = downloadedDate.getTime() - nowDate.getTime();
                long dateDaysDifference = TimeUnit.DAYS.convert(diff, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
                System.out.println ("Days: " + dateDaysDifference);
                // If the downloaded Video is older than 7 days then Delete it
                if(dateDaysDifference > 7l)
                    MediaDownloadManager.getInstance(getBaseContext()).deleteMediaFile(downloadEntity);
            }
        }
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: is the IntentService in the same package as the one mentioned in Manifest

Comment: yes, its in the same package.

Answer (score 0):

try changing the end tag from

```
<service
        android:name=".RemoveDownloadService"
        android:exported="false"/>
```

to

```
<service
        android:name=".RemoveDownloadService"
        android:exported="false">
</service>
```

for some devices running android 4.3 the `requestCode` should **not** be 0

```
int requestCode = 1;
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, requestCode, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

also might need to add `stopSelf();` to the end of `onHandleIntent()`

Comment: my code is running ONLY on 'Samsung device' and its not running on 'Infinix, Huawei and QMobile devices'. what could be the reason :S ?

Comment: all the mobiles (except for Infinix) are triggering the intent only that some of them are taking much longer than expected.